# Flexible Spending Account & Job Change

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, fsa

I worked full-time for Company A from 01-01-14 to 03-14-14. I still work for Company A as an hourly, unbenefitted employee. I started full-time with Company B on 03-24-14. The insurance coverage for the two did not overlap. I had originally elected to put $800 into my FSA with Company A at the beginning of the year. While the insurance considered a job change as a change in life event, I am still being charged for the FSA account every time I work a day with Company A. I have $502.61 remaining in this FSA from Company A. Since I am still contributing to Company A's FSA (against my will), can I use the remaining $502.61 for expenses occurred when using Company B's insurance?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you may use the Feb for any eligible health care expense even if you have insurance with company B. The only possible issue is if you have a High Deductible Health Plan and Health Savings Account. You can't contribute to an HSA if you have a regular FSA. But you maybe able to switch to a limited FSA which allows reimbursement for dental and vision only. It's a little complicated but HR should be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Even if you end up not contributing the full $800.

Comment: Got flagged for low quality :)